# Question on comparing 2 column values and setting value of an adjacent column to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to compare values on 2 different columns values to ensure that they exist(on Sheet 1)
Once the script is aware that they exist I need to access sheet1's column for quantity and add that value to sheet 2's quantity column. The problem is I am unsure of how to just get the location/index of the foreach loop and offset a setValue to another column without setting the value to the entire column(I dont want to do that if the product name of column A does not exist in Sheet1)

Here is the code example of how i am trying to do it

I have included it in a pastebin because I could not figure out how to format the code to paste ( sorry i'm super new at this!)

```
<https://pastebin.com/EKB2n9kA>
```

Sheet1 incoming data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eLNeOZZbdeCDfMMImksVRnBXwKxpHIO_/view?usp=sharing

Sheet2 'base' data to add quantity values to https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h26H9eQgZapd2Y0LVamhRPYme-8LmVF0/view?usp=sharing

example of expected/wanted results https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-0ozD5PrbIq-otG4j7kAyLufQFjDR5Hi/view?usp=sharing

I have also attached 3 different reference photos

Sheet 1 is 'incoming' data to read
Sheet 2 is our 'base' data and where Sheet1's quantity column needs to be added to
the third screenshot is the expected result(having the script skip over rows that do not contain matching data but still being able to get the quantity value based on the index/location the value was found)

Any insight on how to achieve this would be sincerely appreciated

I have tried pushing the results into an empty array but it does not seem to give much useful info the way I am doing it.

I have also tried just getting an offset range (getRange("G2:G").offset(0,3).setValues() to set the results but it sets the value of the entire column instead of only where the values match for each column being compared.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Your images are images in your account which exposes both of our emails so I'm not interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `<https://pastebin.com/EKB2n9kA>`, it seems that your current script is as follows.

```js
function compareCol() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var datA = s1.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var datB = s2.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var quantityA = s1.getRange("C2:C").getValues();
  var quantityB = s2.getRange("D2:D");
  let matchingCol = [];
  for (var i in datA) {
    for (var x in datB[i]) {
      if (datA[i][0] === datB[x][0]) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the if statement in the loop has no script. And, `quantityA`, `quantityB`, and `matchingCol` are not used.

When your script is modified for achieving your goal, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function compareCol() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var datA = s1.getRange("A2:C" + s1.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, [a, , c]) => (o[a] = c, o), {});
  var datB = s2.getRange("A2:D" + s2.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var matchingCol = datB.map(([a, , , d]) => [datA[a] || d]);
  s2.getRange(2, 4, matchingCol.length).setValues(matchingCol);
}
```

- In this modification, when the value of column "A" in "Sheet2" is not found from column "A" of "Sheet1", the value of column "D" of "Sheet2" is used. If you want to remove this, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var matchingCol = datB.map(([a, , , d]) => [datA[a] || d]);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var matchingCol = datB.map(([a]) => [datA[a] || null]);
    ```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Wow! That worked so wonderfully!! I get so confused with the map and reduce functions (Especially since o, a, c or d is never referenced or stored but it can be used in the function) But this worked flawlessly! Thank you for the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help

```
function comparingColumns() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const [h,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    //comparing column A to Column D
    if (r[0] == r[3]) {
      //getting column G of same row in sheet1
      osh.getRange(i + 2, 7).setValue(r[6]);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I was unfortunately not able to store const [h, vs] for some reason as it says 'h is not defined' however  i do think I understand the flow of logic and the use of forEach, thanks for the thoughtful post!

Comment: It's `const [h,...vs]` and it's an assignment.  It defines both h and vs.  It works.  I tested it.

Comment: Your right! there was a period after getSheetByName("Sheet1") that was making the script error. It runs great and has really helped me understand different ways to achieve the same goal. Thank you for the response!

Comment: I probably messed it up when I copied it.